# How to fix Jupyter Notebook pandas error (OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am currently working on the Yelp regression project in a Machine Learning course.

The project requires me to open a Jupyter notebook and import pandas as py.

I use the Anaconda navigator to open Jupyter notebook. I get the following:

> (OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application)

when I try to import pandas for my code. The full message:

```
OSError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ed70324e10b6> in <module>

----> 1 import pandas as pd
2 

3 
businesses = pd.read_json('yelp_business.json', lines = True)

4 reviews = pd.read_json('yelp_review.json', lines = True)

5 users = pd.read_json('yelp_user.json', lines = True)


~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>

9 for dependency in hard_dependencies:

10 try:

---> 11 __import__(dependency)

12 except ImportError as e:

13 missing_dependencies.append("{0}: {1}".format(dependency, str(e)))


~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
138 

139 # Allow distributors to run custom init code

--> 140 from . import _distributor_init

141 

142 from . import core


~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>

24 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL

25 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?

---> 26 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

27 DLL_filenames.append(filename)

28 if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:


~\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)

354 

355 if handle is None:

--> 356 self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

357 else:

358 self._handle = handle


OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I've already tried uninstalling and installing python, anaconda, and pandas.

[My course](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/machine-learning/informationals/predict-a-yelp-rating-regression) from Codeacademy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably downloaded the 64-bit pandas on a 32-bit system. Uninstall and reinstall but pay extra attention to this.

Comment: I uninstalled anaconda and removed all files associated with it. I reinstalled anaconda navigator but this time running as administrator. This changed the file location. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark this as correct if it helped

Answer (score 2):

lt is likely that your environment is messed up. As you can see from the traceback, there are two python environments involved here:

`C:\Users\nouma\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37`

`C:\Users\nouma\Anaconda3`

Please make sure your `PATH` is clean and you can actually remove one of them first.