# Problem with opening an Excel file with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I encounter this problem trying to open an excel file with the following code :

```
#===================================
#different import 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

section_copper = 50.11*8.04#[mm2]
section_alu = 50.18*5.07 #[mm2]
section_composite = 53.24*4.49 #[mm2]
section_steel = 50.35*10.23 #[mm2]
length = 400 #[mm]

data_steel = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\MAPR2481-Lab1.xlsx",sheet_name=0)
data_aluminium = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\MAPR2481-Lab1.xlsx",sheet_name=1)
data_copper = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\MAPR2481-Lab1.xlsx",sheet_name=2)
data_composite = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\MAPR2481-Lab1.xlsx",sheet_name=3)
```

The following message can be found in the console :

```
runfile('C:/Users/Alex/.spyder-py3/lab 1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Alex/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-16-9c6aa501dded>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Alex/.spyder-py3/lab 1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Alex/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Alex/.spyder-py3/lab 1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np

  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 143, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init

  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid  Win32 application
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me !

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667578/how-to-fix-jupyter-notebook-pandas-error-oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-va)

You are using Anaconda i assume.

You have installed the wrong version of python, like you have a 32bit system and u installed 64bit version of python.

Solution: re-install Anaconda as administrator (but first delete the first and all associated files with it).

hope this solves your issue.